# Desktop C# app that integrates with facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, native

I've been working on a native **C# Windows App** that integrates with **Facebook**. However, i keep getting the same error no matter what I do with my code or even if i change the **Facebook Developer > App settings** *(You are not logged in. Please log in and try again)*. Basically, I want my users to login through Facebook while my app retrieves there email & name & phone number (still in progress)

My app never logs in to Facebook, even when i try a static URL *(https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1521075254860950&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html)*

I believe it has something to do with my "**Valid OAuth redirect URIs**" but i've played around for a bit with no luck. So please, if anyone could spot my mistake I would be eternally grateful! :)

Thanks, and have a good day!

```
private string GenerateLoginUrl()
    {
        string ApplicationID = "app_id";
        string ApplicationSecret = "app-secret";
        string ExtendedPermissionsNeeded = "email,offline_access";

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();

        parameters.client_id = ApplicationID;
        parameters.redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
        parameters.response_type = "token";
        parameters.display = "popup";

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ExtendedPermissionsNeeded))
            parameters.scope = ExtendedPermissionsNeeded;

        var fb = new FacebookClient();

        Uri loginUri = fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);

        return loginUri.AbsoluteUri;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var tempUrl = GenerateLoginUrl();
        //webBrowser.Navigate(tempUrl);                                                                                                             //dynamic
        label.Text = tempUrl.ToString();
        webBrowser.Navigate("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=app_id&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html");   //static
        //webBrowser.Navigate("https://www.facebook.com/login/");   //static login
    }
```

Comment: is that your real appID and secret?

Comment: thanks, i've removed them :)

Comment: there is a history on stackoverflow. you should change your app secret in the app settings.

Comment: Calling that URL you mentioned in my browser, I get the login dialog asking me to grant your app permissions – so there is nothing wrong with the configuration per se. However, you can not perform the steps necessary to exchange the code for a token, if you are not returning to a URL within your own app. In this case, you need to choose the dialog mode that returns an access token directly “in” the redirect URI, as a hash fragment (parameter `response_type`, see docs on manually building a login flow for details.) And FYI, the user’s phone number is not available via API at all.

Comment: I've already changed my app secret, thanks for your concern :)

Regarding the error, I've fixed that aswell. I'd like to post my fix just incase someone faces the same issue. Problem was my **Valid OAuth redirect URIs contained:** ttps://facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
while my **Redirect URI contained:** ttps://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html

* Notice the missing **"www"**, that's what was causing the login error :)